# Lissajous plots - additive synthesis

Tags: fourier-transform

I am using Fourier analysis to recreate my data. I have some test data to work on as a way of testing out my synthesis approach. I have spatial test data in the x and y directions. when I plot x against y I get a oval shape. I have completed a frequency analysis and have two peaks in the x direction data and three in the y direction data. I synthesis my data taking the complex number at the frequencies at then using the following equations;

$$x(t) = a_1 \cos(2 \pi f_1 t)+b_1 \sin(2 \pi f_1 t) + a_2 \cos(4 \pi f_1 t) + b_2 \sin(4 \pi f_1 t)$$
$$y(t) =a_{1b} \cos(2 \pi f_1 t) + b_{1b} \sin(2 \pi f_1 t) + a_{2b} \cos(4 \pi f_1 t) + b_{2b} \sin(4 \pi f_1 t) + a_{3b} \cos(6 \pi f_1 t) + b_{3b} \sin(2 \pi f_1 t)$$

a values = real part of amplitude

b values = imaginary part of amplitude

When I then plot x and Y against eachother clearly I get a [Lissajous curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve), however I want to recreate the shape that my original data gave. I have tried to do this in a number of ways but I was wondering if someone could advise me on the best way to present this data?

Comment: It's very hard to "debug" somebody's data without seeing it. Just because your data forms a Lissajous curve doesn't mean that harmonic analysis is the best way to go. Planetary orbits, for instance, are ellipses, but the motion projected onto the x and y axes is not harmonic, because the angular velocity in the Kepler problem is not constant. I don't suppose that's your problem, it's just meant to illustrate why you should show us your data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I will upload my data as soon as possible as I had a few problems doing so earlier. Thank you so much for taking a look.

Comment: To be honest I am a little confused, I don't want to plot a lissajous curve. I would like to recreate the shape I have when plotting x against y ( when I did fourier analysis on this data both had cyclical content and similar fundamental frequencies) however it has brought to my mind an important question about fourier synthesis. Surely when I synthesise my data and the plot it against another synthesised signal I will always get a lissajous curve as I am plotting sin waves against eachother. Isn't this a flaw

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. "Lissajous curve" is just a name. There is no value judgement attached to names in physics. I gave you an example where the physical dynamics is not that of multiple harmonic oscillators (at least not in the trivial sense of the word even though there are transformations in Hamiltonian theory which can make the Kepler problem look harmonic) and you will still get a nice ellipse, just as you would from a sine and a cosine with unequal amplitudes. May I suggest that you post details of your experiment and the data and then we look at it?

Comment: Hi Curious one there seems to be a problem with me attaching my data?

Comment: is there somewhere I can send the data as I am having trouble uploading here

Comment: Why don't you tell us where the data came from? How was it generated?

Comment: It is data from a mechanical wing. hence why I was hoping to trace out the ellipse shape that my real data shows but when I do a synthesis I have instead lots of figure 8 which I know comes from plotting sin waves against eachother

Comment: Assuming that you have an almost harmonic motion, I would say that you are weighing the second harmonic on either x or y way too high. An ellipse is formed by one sine and one cosine with the same frequency but different amplitudes (same amplitudes give circle). If one channel has twice the frequency of the other, then you can get a figure eight (plot sin(t) against sin(2*t)).  Dial down on the higher harmonics and you should do better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Some of my other data gives more of an L shape and again I am struggling to recreate it but I see that it could very well be the weightings on my harmonics. Can I also check; Have I dont it the correct way? Everything else about my approach is OK?

Comment: Hi Curious one can I check my method with you quickly as I am looking at this a number of times now. I have the complex amplitudes so for example say at frequency 1.5 Hz the amplitude is -1.53e+003 + 3.245e+003i then I would use this to give me y(t) = 1.53e+003*cos(2.pi.f1.t)+3.245e+003sin(2.pi.f1.t)

Comment: As much as I would like to help you, without the data none of this is meaningful.